# E_FAIL Error in 7zip

Tags: ubuntu, 7z

I've done a Backup some time ago using 7zip, in which I split the Files in 14 2GB (approximately) files. I'm running Ubuntu Server 15.10.

This is what I'm trying to run in order to extract them:

```
7z x Backup.7z.001
```

Just in case I've also tried (although I don't get the difference between 'x' and 'e'):

```
7z e Backup.7z.001
```

And this is what I get:

```
7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
Processing archive: Backup.7z.001
Error: E_FAIL
```

I've been doing some research and it seems "E_FAIL" error means "lack of disk space". However, I have plenty of diskspace, this is what I get when I run  "df -h"

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

udev                     791M     0  791M   0% /dev

tmpfs                    161M  5,6M  156M   4% /run

/dev/sda2                450G   73G  354G  18% /

tmpfs                    805M  4,0K  805M   1% /dev/shm

tmpfs                    5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock

tmpfs                    805M     0  805M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

tmpfs                    161M     0  161M   0% /run/user/1000


/home/cristian/.Private  450G   73G  354G  18% /home/cristian
```

I have tried in extracting it in many directories /home/cristian, /srv/samba/photos, etc

Comment: show us `strace 7z e Backup.7z.001` results. Which of the presented filesystems are you using ?

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz the result of    strace 7z e Backup.7z.001    is too long to paste here so here's the result: http://pastebin.com/kLpesXEa I'm pretty sure I'm using the 450G's one, or at least I think so

Comment: The `strace` mentions `/srv/samba` which appears to be missing from your list of filesystems?

Comment: @thrig indeed ... pls show us `df /srv/samba`, it seems this is the filesystem you use to extract the files. You should also be able to find out which fs you are using by issuing `df .` before you execute `7z`

Comment: @thrig it gives back `Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      470977904 76170496 370860044  18% /` and when I run it "-h" it echoes `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       450G   73G  354G  18% /`

Comment: Do you have all archive volumes available in the current directory (not just the first `001` part)?

Answer (score 3):

I was copying a 3.5 GB ISO file to a 8 GB USB flash drive.

#### Diagnose

In my case I seconded @kwubbufetowicz and looked at the system calls and signals with strace, see `man strace`:

`strace 7z x [source] -o[target] 2>&1 | tee 7z-strace.log`

Within the last 40 lines or so there is this sequence:

```
open("[path to offending file]", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0664) = 4
[...]
write(4, "[...])..."[...], 131072)          = 131071
munmap(0x7f1c9e0b3000, 135168)          = 0
write(4, "\354", 1)                     = -1 EFBIG (File too large)
close(3)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
brk(0x22be000)                          = 0x22be000
munmap(0x7f1c9c864000, 3837216)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [INT], [...]
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [TERM], [...]
write(1, "xtracting  [some file]/"..., 1108xtracting  [some file] 
[...]
ERROR: E_FAIL                

) = 1108
exit_group(2)                           = ?
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

So there is a pass write on file 4, a fail write on the same file with message **EFBIG (File too large)**, then some file closed, a few interruption and termination signals. Eventually, the error message saw before: **ERROR: E_FAIL**. The offending file is 4.3 GB.

Also, final message sent to the terminal should always reflect the inner message, if you ask me.
In the [OP's pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kLpesXEa), you see

```
 write(1, "Error: E_FAIL                \n", 30Error: E_FAIL  ) = 30
```

which is a consistent message.
In my case 'ERROR: E_FAIL', with uppercase error, on the terminal hides a 'EFBIG (File too large)' in the call-and-signal trace.

**Basically, don't take the stdout at face value and look up in the trace for more, maybe.** Also mind the letter case and whether you get Error: E_FAIL or ERROR: E_FAIL**.

#### Actions

I found this other [blog post](https://theanswersifound.blogspot.com/2014/01/p7zip-efail-when-uncompressing.html) of 2014 in which the author suggests three avenues:

> 1. You are looking at a compressed archive that is read-only, like a CD-ROM and you've asked -7zip to write to that. It can't do this so fails as if there is no disk space.
> 2. You are trying to uncompress to a drive with insufficient disk space.
> 3. You are trying to uncompress a large file to a file system that cannot support a file that large so it fails as if there is no disk space.
>
> My problem was the brand new Flash drive was formatted to exFAT or FAT32 as it appeared to my linux box. Thus the big file (>25GB) couldn't be written above 4GB, which is the limit for FAT32.

**Basically, it is not a matter of space left on disk. Check whether the file system can support the file size you want to write.**

#### Results

This solution worked for me. I reformatted the USB drive from FAT32 to NFTS and could finish the extraction. After extraction the total used space is 5.3 GB.

```
Everything is Ok

Folders: 85
Files: 942
Size:       5437451876
Compressed: 5443010560
) = 3646
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had similar error. The problem was that "file.7z.002" was missing. I only copied "file.7z.001" to new folder by mistake.

Comment: This looks like a fine answer to me. It's not clear if this is the asker's problem too since the error is kind of generic, but it could be